# Python list name causing syntax error

Tags: python, list, syntax-error

In the second function, I keep getting a syntax error on the listExpenseNames list. I've tried changing the name of the variable to ExpenseNamesList, but I got the same error. For both these variable names I also tested with 0 as the index, but that also made no difference. Any help would be appreciated. Also, please don't try to correct any other errors there may be in my code, I want to learn through making mistakes myself. (This may seem contradictory because I just posted asking for a fix, but that's only because I'm stumped and it's preventing me from moving on.)

```
def inputExpenseNames():
    listExpenseNames =[]
    loopExpenseNames = y
    while loopExpenseNames == y:
        listExpenseNames.append = input('Please enter the expense name.')
        loopExpenseNames=input('Would you like to enter another expense? If so, please enter \'y\'')
    print(listExpenseNames)

def inputExpenseAmounts():
    listExpenseAmounts =[]
    loopExpenseAmounts = 0
    while loopExpenseAmounts <= len(inputExpenseNames) :
        listExpenseAmounts.append = input('How much was spent on' listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)]'?')
        loopExpenseAmounts += 1
    print(listExpenseAmounts)
```

Comment: You should add the error message

Comment: Definity, the expression `input('How much was spent on' listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)]'?')` causes an error! Replace it with `input('How much was spent on' +str(listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)]) + '?')`

Comment: First things first `.append` is a method it needs to look like this: `.append()`.

Comment: `input('How much was spent on' listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)]'?')` you need to concatenate with a `+` here.

Comment: Do `listExpenseNames.append(input('Please enter the expense name.'))`

Answer (score 3):

This code has a couple of problems:

1. `listExpenseNames` will not be defined inside `inputExpenseAmounts`. [See Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) for an explanation
2. `l.append = ...` will change the value of the `append` attribute, it won't actually append anything.  To append something do `l.append(...)`
3. As others have pointed out, use `+` to concatenate strings: `'spent on' +  listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)] + '?'`

`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to print the string stored in listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)] for the input display text. You need to concatenate the strings with a + to one string and not only list them after each other:

```
listExpenseAmounts.append = input('How much was spent on' + listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)] + '?')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate strings on the following line but you are not. try the following code instead.

```
listExpenseAmounts.append(input('How much was spent on'+ listExpenseNames[int(loopExpenseAmounts)]'?'))
```